# Overlay pane on a background video not responsive and parallax effect not working on video html css

Tags: html, css, overlay, parallax

Im in need of adding an overlay effect to the background video on a web site design. Eventhough the overlay property is added to the video it does not response to the screen size change as it should be. the size of the overlay varies rapidly but not according to the way with the video. 
this is the css part

```
#video-parallax-video{
z-index: -100;
opacity: 1;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
margin-top:-400px;
}
#video-overlay-features{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #62625E;
color: #fff;
margin-top: -27px;
opacity: 0.7;
z-index:-20;
}
```

here is the html code where Ive added the video and the overlay

```
<div>
<div id="video-overlay-features"></div>
    <video id="video-parallax-video" class="item" preload="metadata" loop autoplay muted width="100%" style="margin-top:-290px">
      <source src="video/web_.webm" type="video/webm" >
    </video>

  </div>
```

Please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advanced

Comment: I have the same issue.  Did you figure out a solution?